# How to pass BlockingQueue?

Tags: java, blockingqueue

There are two classes. One, `X` , has it's own blockingQueue and also method returning it:

```
public int getQueue(){
    return TaskQueue;
}
```

but it seems it returns queue's reference. And I need to operate on it in other class `Y` where there is `x.getQueue().take();` . So is there any way to pass queue with getters / setters ?

Comment: Do you want to work on the original object?

Comment: What do you mean with getters/setters?

Comment: The return type of the `getQueue` method is `int`, so it's not returning a reference to the queue. What is `TaskQueue`? If it's not `int`, then this code will not compile.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public int getQueue()
{
    return TaskQueue;
}
```

You are trying to returning the **TaskQueue class** as an **int** and not your TaskQueue object.

I don't know how's your code structure, but here is an example of what you want to do:

```
class X
{
    private BlockingQueue taskQueue;

    public X()
    {
        taskQueue = new BlockingQueue();
    }

    public BlockingQueue getQueue()
    {
        return taskQueue;
    }
}
```

And you can use this in any other class:

```
X myXClassObject = new X();

myXClassObject.getQueue().blockingQueueMethod();
```

or in a more understandable way:

```
X myXClassObject = new X();

BlockingQueue myQueue = myXClassObject.getQueue();

myQueue.blockingQueueMethod();
myQueue.take();
```

Comment: Oh dear, terrible mistake I made here rewriting the method. In my program it is as a BlockingQueue not as an int. I am so sorry. Though, it is not working there

Comment: Then the problem must be located at the method's return value. Is TaskQueue a Class or an Object?

Comment: Object. But I found the mistake. I was missing  `X myXClassObject = new X();` I must had been bait distracted. Thank You very much. :)